# Calling multiple functions in FutureBuilder causes an error

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-test, flutter-futurebuilder

I am retrieving data from Firestore in the form of two functions (_onpressed() and _drname()) and called both of them in FutureBuilder.

Function 1 is

```
  Future _onPressed() async {
if (widget.brew.id == currentid.userid()) {
  return await db
      .collection('Messages')
      .doc(widget.brew.id)
      .get()
      .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
      print('${documentSnapshot.data()['Message']}');
      String msg = json.encode(documentSnapshot.data()['Message']);
      

      return msg;
    } else {
      print('Document does not exist on the database');
    }
    // var a= documentSnapshot.data()['Message'];
  });
} else {
  return 'No Prescription from doctor yet';
}}
```

Function 2 is

```
Future _drname() async {
if (widget.brew.id == currentid.userid()) {
  return await db
      .collection('Drname')
      .doc(widget.brew.id)
      .get()
      .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
      print('${documentSnapshot.data()['name']}');
      String msg = json.encode(documentSnapshot.data()['name']);
      return msg;
    } else {
      print('Document does not exist on the database');
    }
    // var a= documentSnapshot.data()['Message'];
  });
} else {
  return 'No';
}}
```

Calling these functions in FutureBuilder like this

```
Widget _messagePannel() {
return FutureBuilder(
    future: Future.wait([_onPressed(),_drname()]),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 17.0),
              child: TextButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Call()),
                  );
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.video_call,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 30.0,
                ),
                label: Text(''),
              ),
            )
          ],
          title: Text(
            'Prescrption',
            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'RussoOne', fontSize: 22.0),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
          elevation: 0.0,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Container(
          decoration: image,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      ),
                      color: Colors.black,
                      child: Center(
                          child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0),
                        child: Wrap(
                          children: [
                            Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '${snapshot.data[0]} ',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'RussoOne',
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    letterSpacing: 0.8,
                                    fontSize: 18.0,
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.black),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '${snapshot.data[1]} ',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'RussoOne',
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    letterSpacing: 0.8,
                                    fontSize: 18.0,
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.black),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });}
```

Getting This error from the Debug Console

The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<List>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<List>#44f46):
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling:

[image: Error image]

Answer (score 1):

When using `snapshot`, the initial value for the `data` property is `null` (since Future has no result until you receive the response), so using it straight away as you do it in the code (e.g. `snapshot.data[1]`) should be avoided.

To cope with that, first of all you should check if the data is not null. For that, `snapshot` has a dedicated method `snapshot.hasData`, for instance:

```
return FutureBuilder(
    future: Future.wait([_onPressed(),_drname()]),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator(); // E.g. Show loader if there is no data yet
        }

        return Scaffold(...); // Return the widget you have now
    },
);
```

Comment: Yes it worked Perfectly for me.......Firstly i though of that but didn't implemented

Comment: Great! Do not forget to mark the answer as the correct one if this was helpful.

Comment: thanks, you made my day